# When Payment Fails on a Redirect Payment Method should the Order be Cancelled?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We have a payment method that redirects off the magento site to make payment then returns to the success or failed controller.

When the `Place Order` button is pressed on the Payment page, it redirects to the payment website and **Creates an Order** with no status.

When the payment is successful the Order status is set to `Processing`. If it fails the order is `Cancelled`.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it redirects to the payment website and Creates an Order with no status.

Actually, an order always must have some status.

If your payment gateway can impact on the place order flow, for example, payment can trigger fraud rules and you need to change an order status depends on these rules, the order can have `Pending` status while your payment method will process fraud rules.

Comment: So the order is created when you click `place order`...if I check in the back end that order has no status

Comment: Do you use some customized flow? Or perform place order after a redirect from payment gateway? The `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\State\AuthorizeCommand::execute` sets order status and this method triggers on `payment-information` WEB API call.

Comment: Please answer the question: When Payment Fails on a Redirect Payment Method should the Order be Cancelled?

Comment: @StevieG, it depends on your integration. If a customer should not be able to do anything with failed payment - then the order should have `Canceled` status. If your integration requires some actions from customer or admin - like a fraud resolving, the order might have  `Pending` status.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes in this case it is done and dusted failed.